# clever loop needed - sort through DateTime column and measure crowding

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

i want to asses the population of an ER per hour . the definition is as follows : 
crowd(Hour=x) = people who weren't discharged(hour=x-1)+people who joined(hour=x) - people who were discharged(hour=x)

i use a pandas dataframe and the date and time of register and date and time of discharge are written '2013-01-01 01:41:01' .

what would be the most simple and elegant way to create this crowd(hour) data ?
i thought about just writing a very specific for loop and a count function but i will gladly consider your insights before jumping head first into such a quest (: !

in many cases the discharge date and time is NAN , that is because these cases were not discharged but transferred to a certain department of the hospital.

example

lets say i have this dataset

```
case    RegisterDateTime    DischargeDateTime.   TransferDateTime
 0    '2013-01-01 00:12:00'    '2013-01-01 00:48:00'    NAN
 1    '2013-01-01 00:43:00'    '2013-01-01 02:12:00'    NAN
 2    '2013-01-01 00:56:00'    '2013-01-01 01:22:00'    NAN
 3    '2013-01-01 01:04:00'    '2013-01-01 04:12:00'    NAN
 4    '2013-01-01 01:34:00'    '2013-01-01 04:52:00'    NAN
 5    '2013-01-01 02:01:00'    NAN    '2013-01-01 05:34:00'
```

so i would want to have a dataset 'crowd' which could tell me for everyday and every hour what is the amount of people present . 
in this example we can see 
crowd('2013-01-01',0)= 2  (why ? because there are no pre-registered cases ,cases 0,1,2 registered during 0th hour and case 0 discharged ->0+3-1=2 )
crowd('2013-01-01',1)= 3 (why? cases 1,2 are pre-registered , cases 3,4 registered during 1th hour, case 2 discharged ->2+2-1=3 )
i hope the idea is clear now .

also , about discharge and transfer , they complement each other so i just need to figure out how to join them together into one column and erase NANs

Comment: Hey buddy! Can you post a sample of your current data set (fake data of course) and desired output

Comment: i edited the main post with more details !

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you've already tried, and what in particular you're struggling with.  For example, are you having trouble coalescing the discharged and transferred columns into a single "left the ER" column?  Are you having trouble consolidating timestamped rows into summaries for the hour?

Comment: I'm sorry enter, I can't make sense of your question, can you try to re explain?

Comment: Datanovice - i had a problem with the syntax , changed it - hope everything is clear now . if not i'll provide further details .

Comment: kevin - i'm new to pandas so i was hoping through this post i could figure out what is the optimal way to tackle this question and learn simultanously .
'left the ER' column is not what troubles me . more like ; should i use groupby to join all registered in a certain day and then another groupby to join all of a certain day and a certain hour ? is there a built-in count function for  groupby ? maybe there's a better function to use ... that's what i aim for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Very much along the idea that you described in your post but it's a lengthy series of steps. Perhaps, someone else may have a shorter implementation.

```
import pandas as pd

>>>df
   case RegisterDateTime DischargeDateTime TransferDateTime
0     0      1/1/13 0:12       1/1/13 0:48              NaN
1     1      1/1/13 0:43       1/1/13 2:12              NaN
2     2      1/1/13 0:56       1/1/13 1:22              NaN
3     3      1/1/13 1:04       1/1/13 4:12              NaN
4     4      1/1/13 1:34       1/1/13 4:52              NaN
5     5      1/1/13 2:01               NaN      1/1/13 5:34

# Construct population outflow. This is where you merge Discharges with Transfers
df_out = pd.DataFrame([(j,k) if str(k) != 'nan' else (j,v) for j, k, v in zip(df['case'], df['DischargeDateTime'],df['TransferDateTime'])])
df_out.columns = ['out', 'time']
# You can skip this if your column is already in DateTime
df_out['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_out['time'])
# Needed for resampling
df_out.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df_out = df_out.resample('H').count().cumsum()
# Needed for merging later
df_out.reset_index(inplace=True)

>>>df_out
                     out
time                    
2013-01-01 00:00:00    1
2013-01-01 01:00:00    2
2013-01-01 02:00:00    3
2013-01-01 03:00:00    3
2013-01-01 04:00:00    5
2013-01-01 05:00:00    6

# Now, repeat for the population inflow
df_in = df.loc[:, ['case', 'RegisterDateTime']]
df_in.columns = ['in', 'time']
df_in['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_in['time'])
df_in.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df_in = df_in.resample('H').count().cumsum()
df_in.reset_index(inplace=True)

>>>df_in
                     in
time                   
2013-01-01 00:00:00   3
2013-01-01 01:00:00   5
2013-01-01 02:00:00   6


# You can now combine the two
df= pd.merge(df_in, df_out)
df['population'] = df['in'] - df['out']

>>>df
                 time  in  out  population
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00   3    1           2
1 2013-01-01 01:00:00   5    2           3
2 2013-01-01 02:00:00   6    3           3
```